# Starting and Stopping concurrent threads through Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mef

I am new to .NET environment. I need a windows service whose `Start` and `Stop` method will call a specific class, say MainContext's Start and Stop method respectively. The MainContext class will contain the list of extensions loaded through [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/). Each extensions needs to be run as a separate thread in concurrent manner.

The class `MainContext` will contain two public methods `Start` and `Stop`, both of return type void and containing no arguments. On calling `Start` method, it will start the thread for each extensions loaded through MEF in an concurrent manner. While the `Stop` method will stop all the threads started by `Start` method.

Which is the best threading practice in this situation? I am confused. Should I use `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` class or `System.Threading.Thread` class for multi-threading or should I use any other technique? Which would be better suited to my requirements and would provide me more flexibility and stability?

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread` suits your needs instead of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`, however you also need the some logic inside your thread methods to stop the thread.

Comment: Let's imagine, that you have 100 extensions and one dual core processor. Starting of 100 threads will not help you program make its work faster in this case. You should tell something about the nature of your extensions - what kind of work are they performing?

Comment: @Dennis: 100 extensions would not be the case in my application. Say, at the most 5 to 8 extensions would be running concurrently. And, there is no heavy duty work for each extension. It would be very simple and light weight work, say file system watching, etc.

Comment: My first question is.. do you need to need any logic inside your thread methods to stop the threads?  This may be one of those cases where you actually do in order to as to provide a reliable cleanup of the extensions, (don't know MAF), but I had to ask, after all, it may be possible to simply let the service stop.

Comment: @Kunal Shah: "File system watching" means that your threads will sleep almost time. You should not create separate threads for IO-bound operations, use APM instead. You've asked about the best practice: best practice is "don't create threads manually". There is some rare cases, when manually creating a thread is necessary, but for common tasks let the thread pool manage threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar using MAF, with add-ins watching file servers, databases, and web services. The Windows service invokes Start and Stop methods in each add-in, which in turn enable or disable System.Timer.Timers. The actual processing is done on each timer's elapsed event handler, which runs on a pooled thread.

One of the add-ins watches a database table that's used inter-process communication so that I can monitor and control the other add-ins from a UI app.